# how can i refresh just the modal with ajax call without losing JavaScript tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

so im working on this library project where students can order books and admin has to confirm those requests from his side.
here is a pic of the project to have a small idea:
[those are students requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAI1N.png)

when u click on the blue button you can see more details of the student order:[order details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqmd4.png)

as you can see there is the book that the student has ordered.
now what i wanted is to refresh just the modal after the admin click accept and i did achieve that by using the .load() function here is the piece of code that responsible that :[code that load the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oxom.png)
since we have multiple students and they can order multiple books so i had to use 2 loops that why you see those dynamic id on the modal id and button id, $tmp is for the students loop and $tmp2 is for the books loop. so far so good, the problem is when the modal refresh i lose my script tag which is bad why because all my buttons have click events so no script means buttons will not work here is before and after modal refresh [before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Xr4.png) you can see the script tag that responsible for the buttons and the ajax call [here is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfQ6V.png) as you can see the modal refresh successfully but i lost my script so the buttons will not work so i have to reload the whole page so i can retrieve my script then the buttons will work again.
some of the solutions i tried is to put the script outside of the modal because i assumed .load() can only fetch html no script but i can't because i need the script to be inside that loop in the modal for the books button

here is the modal code if you want more details :

```
                                <!--  user books details modal -->
                       
                                <div class="modal fade" id="userBooksDetails<?= $tmp ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ">
                                        <div id="modalContent<?= $tmp ?>" class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="modalBody<?= $tmp ?>" class="modal-body">

                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th scope="col">Picture</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <?php
                                                      //dont mind this its just to fetch information of the book to display it in the modal
                                                        $livre = new  Livre();
                                                        $exemplaire = $livre->myBooks($user->id);
                                                    
                                                        if ($exemplaire) {
                                                            //here is the second loop because student can order multiple books and each book request need to have an unique id for it button 
                                                            foreach ($exemplaire as $exem) {

                                                                $tmp2--;
                                                                $copy = Exemplaire::find($exem['Num_Exemp']);
                                                                $book = Livre::find($copy->ISBN);
                                                        ?>
                                                        <script>
                                                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                                                       
                                                                      
                                                                        
                                                                        //request for accepting the order of the user  
                                                                        $("#acceptBook<?= $tmp2 ?>").click(function() {
                                                                            let copyId = $(this).attr("data-idCopy");

                                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                                url: "<?= PROOT ?>emprunts/acceptOrder/" + copyId,
                                                                                type: "POST",
                                                                                success: function(data) {
                                                                                    $("#modalContent<?= $tmp ?>").load(window.location.href + " #modalContent<?= $tmp ?>" );
                                                                                    console.log(data)
                                                                                    
                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        });
                                                                        

                                                                        //request for rejecting the order of the user 
                                                                        $("#rejectBook<?= $tmp2 ?>").click(function() {
                                                                            let copyId = $(this).attr("data-idCopy");

                                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                                url: "<?= PROOT ?>emprunts/rejectOrder/" + copyId,
                                                                                type: "POST",
                                                                                success: function(data) {
                                                                                    //$("#userBooksDetails<?= $tmp ?>").load(" #userBooksDetails<?= $tmp ?>");
                                                                                    console.log(data);
                                                                                    $("#modalBody<?= $tmp ?>").load(window.location.href + " #modalBody<?= $tmp ?>" );

                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        });

                                                                        //request for returning the book (is not working after reloading on accept fix it )
                                                                        $("#return<?= $tmp2 ?>").click(function() {
                                                                            let copyId = $(this).attr("data-idCopy");

                                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                                url: "<?= PROOT ?>emprunts/returnBook/" + copyId,
                                                                                type: "POST",
                                                                                success: function(data) {
                                                                                    console.log(data);
                                                                                    $("#modalBody<?= $tmp ?>").load(window.location.href + " #modalBody<?= $tmp ?>" );

                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        })
                                                                    })
                                                                </script>

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th> <img src="<?= PROOT . "/public/img/books/" . $book->img ?>" class="w-50 rounded-t-5 rounded-tr-md-0 rounded-bl-md-5" aria-controls="#picker-editor">
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <td class="display-6 text-align-center">
                                                                        <div class="my-5">
                                                                            <?= $book->Titre_livre ?>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div class="form-group  mt-4">
                                                                            <button id="stat<?= $tmp2 ?>" disabled class="btn mt-5"><?php if($exem['isConfirm']==0)
                                                                                            echo "Not Confirmed";
                                                                                            else echo "Confirmed"; ?></button>      
                                                                        </div>

                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td id="test<?= $tmp2 ?>">
                                                                  <!--  here im checking if the book is confirmed if yes im showing some specific buttons if not hiding some buttons -->
                                                                        <div class="form-group  mt-5">
                                                                            <a <?php if($exem['isConfirm']==1)
                                                                                            echo "hidden";
                                                                                            else
                                                                                            echo "" ?> 
                                                                                            id="acceptBook<?= $tmp2 ?>" class="btn  m-2" data-idCopy="<?= $exem['Num_Exemp'] ?>"  role="button">Accept</a>
                                                                            <a <?php if($exem['isConfirm']==1)
                                                                                            echo "hidden";
                                                                                            else
                                                                                            echo "" ?>  id="rejectBook<?= $tmp2 ?>" class="btn btn-dark m-2" data-idCopy="<?= $exem['Num_Exemp'] ?>" role="button">Reject</a>
                                                                            <a <?php if($exem['isConfirm']==0)
                                                                                            echo "hidden";
                                                                                            else
                                                                                            echo "" ?>  id="return<?= $tmp2?>" data-idCopy="<?= $exem['Num_Exemp'] ?>"  class="btn btn-secondary mt-4"> Return </a>

                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                        <?php }
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>



                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-mdb-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: That script should rather not be inside the loop to begin with. Go read up on _event delegation_, to have your event handlers cover _new_ elements that get added to the document dynamically later on, to begin with. And if you need any data from "within" your loop, in your JavaScript - then place that information into _custom data attributes_ on the affected elements, so that your script can then read it from there.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the comment i read about the event delegation its really interesting concept, i tried to apply that concept on my case but i struggled a lot, i didnt even know how to start, im quite newbie to all this :(